# Column not found execption in servlet login application

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, authentication

I'm developing login application using java servlet and mysql and I'm getting following error when I'm trying to login by giving username and password.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'alex' not found.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.findColumn(ResultSet.java:987)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet.getString(ResultSet.java:5584)
at org.kaveen.login.database.LoginDaoImpl.userValidate(LoginDaoImpl.java:36)
at org.kaveen.login.controller.Login.doPost(Login.java:44)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
..................................
```

This is my LoginDaoImpl class

```
public class LoginDaoImpl implements LoginDao {

public String userValidate(LoginBean loginBean) {

    String userName = loginBean.getUserName();

    String password = loginBean.getPassword();
    System.out.println(userName);
    System.out.println(password);
    String sql = "select username,password from users";
    String userNameDB = "";
    String userPasswordDb = "";

    Connection connection = null;
    java.sql.Statement statement = null;

    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    try {
        connection = DbConnecton.setConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            userNameDB = resultSet.getString(userName);
            userPasswordDb = resultSet.getNString(password);
            if (userName.equals(userNameDB)
                    && password.equals(userPasswordDb)) {
                return "Success";
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "Failed invalid credentials";
   }
  }
```

Can any one please explain why I'm getting this error? and how can I fix it?.

Comment: Parameter for [`getString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(java.lang.String)) should be a **column label**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to login with a username called "alex"? here is your error:

```
userNameDB = resultSet.getString(userName);
```

When using the method getString on a ResultSet you can specify the column index (starting from 1) of the column in the result, or the column name (in your case the column name is "username"). You are passing the actual username to the method and of course that column does not exist.

try this:

```
userNameDB = resultSet.getString("username");
```

Answer (score 0):

What your are doing is very wrong. your query gets all the rows from users table and your are iterating over it.

to correct it you have to pass the name of the column when getting data from result set.

```
userNameDB = resultSet.getString(userNameColumn);
userPasswordDb = resultSet.getNString(passwordColumn);
```

but this way is very stupid. you can do this in your database with a simple query.
with this query there is no need for iteration.

```
select * from users where username_col=username and password_col=password
```

assuming that you store passwords in raw text which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare a single SQL query to check if your user credentials are matching, looping over a result set can be costly (when number of user is high).

```
String sql = "select username, password from users where username=:username and password = :pass";

Connection connection = null;
java.sql.Statement statement = null;

ResultSet resultSet = null;

try {
    connection = DbConnecton.setConnection();
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    resultSet= statement.executeQuery(sql);
    resultSet.setString("username", username );
    resultSet.setString("pass", password );
    if (resultSet.hasNext()){ // check if we had found someone with same username and password
       return "Success";
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
 if(connection!=null)// finaly remember to close connection if open
 connection.close()
}
return "Failed invalid credentials";
```